# fatal: destination path '/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer' already exists and is not an empty directory

Tags: python, git, docker, ipython

I was trying to reproduce the [project to predict the results of the 2014 world cup](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ipython-soccer-predictions) from Google. (ipython-soccer predictions)

I was going through "How to deploy" section of that link. Everything was oright until this line comes up

```
sudo docker run -p 8888:8888 fhoffa/ipython-predictions:v1
```

Running this code gives me the following result

```
2015-07-16 17:00:24,514 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 10
2015-07-16 17:00:24,516 INFO spawned: 'gitpull-predictions' with pid 11
2015-07-16 17:00:25,420 INFO exited: gitpull-predictions (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-07-16 17:00:26,422 INFO success: ipython entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-07-16 17:00:26,422 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-07-16 17:00:26,424 INFO spawned: 'gitpull-predictions' with pid 23
2015-07-16 17:00:26,429 INFO exited: gitpull-predictions (exit status 128; not expected)
2015-07-16 17:00:28,433 INFO spawned: 'gitpull-predictions' with pid 24
2015-07-16 17:00:28,441 INFO exited: gitpull-predictions (exit status 128; not expected)
2015-07-16 17:00:31,447 INFO spawned: 'gitpull-predictions' with pid 25
2015-07-16 17:00:31,452 INFO exited: gitpull-predictions (exit status 128; not expected)
2015-07-16 17:00:32,453 INFO gave up: gitpull-predictions entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

So i thought the problem is related to the `gitpull-predictions`. Then i looked at the log file named `gitpull-predictions-stderr---supervisor-KmqU8Z.log`, which says:

```
fatal: destination path '/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

The directory `/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer` does not exist before running the `docker run`, however this error comes up with running the code.

Then i looked up the config file named 'supervisord-extra.conf'. 
In this file it says

```
[program:gitpull-predictions]
command=/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ipython-soccer-predictions.git /home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer
```

So I think this 'gitpull-predictions' does the 'git clone' from a address given to /home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer directory . But i think this command 'git clone' is running, not only once, but many times even after it clones the files into the directory. So '/home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer' exists after 'docker run' command, but then 'git clone' runs many times giving that 'fatal destination' error.

Next thing i did was editing the config file like following

```
[program:gitpull-predictions]
startsecs = 0
autorestart = false
command=/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ipython-soccer-predictions.git /home/ipy/ipynotebooks/soccer
```

I have added those two lines, startsecs = 0, and autorestart = false.
When i run the 'docker run' again the message shows

```
2015-07-16 18:50:43,258 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-07-16 18:50:43,259 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-ssh.conf" during parsing
2015-07-16 18:50:43,259 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-extra.conf" during parsing
2015-07-16 18:50:43,259 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-ipython.conf" during parsing
2015-07-16 18:50:43,284 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-07-16 18:50:43,284 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-07-16 18:50:43,285 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-07-16 18:50:43,285 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-07-16 18:50:43,286 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2015-07-16 18:50:44,288 INFO spawned: 'ipython' with pid 11
2015-07-16 18:50:44,290 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 12
2015-07-16 18:50:44,291 INFO spawned: 'gitpull-predictions' with pid 13
2015-07-16 18:50:44,304 INFO success: gitpull-predictions entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2015-07-16 18:50:45,204 INFO exited: gitpull-predictions (exit status 0; expected)
2015-07-16 18:50:46,205 INFO success: ipython entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-07-16 18:50:46,206 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Still gitpull-predictions exits (not expected)
Then I looked at the error log that shows

```
Cloning into 'ipython-soccer-predictions'...
```

Still doesnt run sucessfully. Is there any solution to it? 
Im starting to wonder why 'git clone' is used for the programme named 'gitpull'. Name of the programme should be 'gitclone'...

Comment: What debugging have you done? What do you think `gitpull-predictions` is doing?

Comment: I made slight modifications on the topic. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Have you tried entering the container and seeing if the directory is already there? I went to that repo you linked to, but don't see a Dockerfile there. Do you know what CMD is being run, or where the Dockerfile might be?

Comment: i typed in 'sudo docker run fhoffa/ipython-predictions:v1' to get the docker file. And the directory is already there after doing 'docker run'. Then if i change it to a new directory, the same error message comes up.